# Hardware lock excel sheet using MAC ID externally

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a Macro that will fetch the Mother Board Seriel Number of the machine running the Excel once opened.

It will then validate if this Seriel Number is present in my Sheet1 the VBA and if it is present, it will open up the Excel else it will close it.

Following is the code to get Seriel Number.

```
Public Function MBSerialNumber() As String
Dim objs As Object                                                                                                                     
Dim obj As Object
Dim WMI As Object
Dim sAns As String
Set WMI = GetObject("WinMgmts:")
Set objs = WMI.InstancesOf("Win32_BaseBoard")
For Each obj In objs
    sAns = sAns & obj.SerialNumber
    If sAns < objs.Count Then sAns = sAns & ","
Next
MBSerialNumber = sAns

End Function
```

Following is the validation part

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set RMBSN = Sheets(1).Range("C4") ' This is where you have already stored required MBSerialNumber
    If MBSerialNumber <> RMBSN Then   ' Checking if current machine serial number is matching with required
        MsgBox ("Data Security failier, This workbook will close") ' In case it does not match workbook will be closed
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

What I want to do now is, move the allowed values of my "allowed" seriel numbers outside of the sheet - maybe somewhere online so that I can add those values online without having to feed it in the sheet every single time I want to give someone access.

Is this possible? Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is this file stored? On a network drive? You could move it to a `.txt` or `database file` but then you had to decrypt the values in someway and it requires to have access to the file.

Comment: How does this "security" hold up when the workbook is opened with macros disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of mbserial number in cell c4 in sheet1 and then run workbook_open